# How to apply MPSImageGuidedFilter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, filter, metal

I applied OpenCV guided filter for my project in Python successfully and now I have to carry this function to my iOS application. I searched Apple developer website and found out a filter called [`MPSImageGuidedFilter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/mpsimageguidedfilter). I suppose it works in a similar way as OpenCV guided filter. However, my limited knowledge of iOS programming does not let me figure out how to use it. Unfortunately, I could not find a sample code on the web too. Is there anyone who used this filter before? I really appreciate the help. Or a sample code using any filter under MPS would be helpful to figure out.

Comment: Welcome! I'm afraid your question is way too broad for StackOverflow. It's basically "How do I use Metal Performance Shaders to process images?". I recommend you use Core Image, which is a higher level of abstraction, and provides the same filter as `CIGuidedFilter`.

Comment: Hello Frank, thank you. CIGuidedFiler does not exist in Apple website. I have found out that it is an open source code. Unfortunately it says it is upsampling the image. This is not what guided filter suppose to do. I am going to apply it to video frames and CIFilters will not be fast enough I assume. I have found out a GitHub repo:https://github.com/MetalKit/mps. It has some info about MPSfilters. I will try to understand how to apply it into my code. 

Comment: Yes, Apple's documentation is no longer maintained, unfortunately. I recommend you use the generated documentation from `cifilter.io`: https://cifilter.io/CIGuidedFilter

Comment: What is a guided filter supposed to do, then? Some kind of bilateral filtering?

Comment: What it does is edge-preserving smoothing filter. I tried OpenCV guided filter in python and I got great results. However I need to run it on IOS. I use it to detect the edges in my  segmentation mask after training my model.It improved the result significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of hard work, I managed to make `MPSImageGUidedFilter`. Please see below the code who wants to work on:

```
import UIKit
import MetalPerformanceShaders
import MetalKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    public var texIn: MTLTexture!
    
    public var coefficient: MTLTexture!

    public var context: CIContext!
    
    let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
    var queue: MTLCommandQueue!
    var Metalview: MTKView { return view as! MTKView }

    override func viewDidLoad() {     
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        Metalview.drawableSize.height = 412
        Metalview.drawableSize.width = 326
        Metalview.framebufferOnly = false
        Metalview.device = device
       
        Metalview.delegate = self
        
        queue = device.makeCommandQueue()
        let textureLoader = MTKTextureLoader(device: device)
        
        let urlCoeff = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mask", withExtension: "png")
        do {
            coefficient = try textureLoader.newTexture(URL: urlCoeff!, options: [:])
        } catch {
            fatalError("coefficient file not uploaded")
        }
        
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "guide", withExtension: "png")
        do {
            texIn = try textureLoader.newTexture(URL: url!, options: [:])
        } catch {
            fatalError("resource file not uploaded")
        }
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: MTKViewDelegate {

    func mtkView(_ view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {}

    func draw(in view: MTKView) {
        guard let commandBuffer = queue.makeCommandBuffer(),
              let drawable = view.currentDrawable else {
            return
        }
      
        let shader = MPSImageGuidedFilter(device: device, kernelDiameter: 5)
        shader.epsilon = 0.001

        let textOut = drawable.texture
        
        shader.encodeReconstruction(to: commandBuffer, guidanceTexture: texIn, coefficientsTexture: coefficient, destinationTexture: textOut)

        commandBuffer.present(drawable)
        commandBuffer.commit()
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey @baymark, what exactly are the mask and guide pngs you use in this example? Where do they come from?

Comment: Hi Jorge, they are true and predicted mask grayscale images. True image is coming from my data set as defined for segmentation such as hair, skin or background. Predicted mask is the outcome of my CNN. Outcome is between 0 and 1 for each pixel. I set a threshold to 0.7.If the pixel value is above the threshold I set it as 1 and 0 for lower values. 1 represents a pixel of the segmented area (hair, skin etc ) and 0  represents a pixel for non segmented (non hair, non skin etc.). This gives me a grayscale image. I process them in the guided filter to create more accurate on the edges of the image